# Redirect example.com:84 to the homepage of main site (example.com)

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have a domain and a few years back there used to be page on this address: `example.com:84` but now there is no page and I want to redirect it to my domain's homepage.

For example, if someone types `example.com:84` then he/she should be redirected to `example.com`.

How can I do this in `.htaccess`?

Comment: Are `domain.com:84` and `domain.com` same domain with different port?

Comment: Yes the domain is same...

Comment: Hey thank you for your efforts. However, I made the changes but the domain still not redirecting to the homepage.

Comment: Silly question, but presumably your server is still configured to accept requests to port 84? And `.htaccess` overrides are enabled? (Although you presumably have server access if you've configured port 84 - so why are you doing this in `.htaccess`?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^84$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: The `HTTP_HOST` variable will also contain the (non-standard) port number, eg. `example.com:84` (so your first condition won't currently match).

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, thanks for the information. I have uploaded the condition.:)